# Retrieving ALL messages published from AWS IOT while my Android phone was offline

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi3

How do I retrieve ALL messages published from  **my raspberry pi 3** **through "AWS IOT via mqtt**" while the end device **(my Android app**)was offline, or switched off?

In other words, after my phone reconnects to the internet or it is powered on, I need my app to receive ALL messages

please note that my raspberry pi 3 is running on python and my Android app is running on Java

I tried to send **three messages** from raspberry pi 3 while m phone is offline, then  i made my phone online. However,  I always receive the last message  and the first and seconds messages do not arrive. is the the problem with the AWS queue and configureOfflinePublishQueueing?

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming that you are publishing and receiving the data in the shadow with Raspberry Pi 3.

First, there is nothing wrong with AWS. The shadow will only give you the details of the current state consider the shadow as the virtual device on the cloud. However, you can use anyone from below.

1. There are is a `meta` JSON format in the AWS Shadow, When there is a mismatch between `desired` and `reported` states (Your Exact scenario). You can fetch the `meta` information from your Android application
2. Make a JSON in such a way that would keep previous state information. However, there is a constraint of 8KB memory in the shadow.
3. Make a trigger from the AWS IoT and log the details in the DynamoDB. In my opinion, this is the best solution if you need to log all the data.